# Самая приватная лицензия на репозиторий?

Tags: лицензирование, repository

Какая самая приватная лицензия на репозиторий? Чтобы только я мог пользоваться моим кодом. Ну и те, кому я дам доступ и тд. Вариант - сделать его приватным - не подходит)

Comment: Никакая лицензия по факту физически не защитит вас от использования вашего кода другими, если вы сами его выложите в открытый доступ.

Comment: Храните свой код в локальном гите и не пушьте в удаленный репозиторий  А кому нужен будет, просто скидывайте через архив. По-моему это **САМЫЙ** приватный способ. Так у вас будет доступ ко всем плюшкам гита, кроме Code Review

Comment: @ulxanxv, мне нужно хранить репозиторий в удаленном доступе. И в то же время, нужно, чтобы он был защищен (хотя бы формально)

Comment: @insolor да, я это прекрасно понимаю. Мне нужно хотя бы для галочки))

Comment: ну так напишите свою лицензию. Делов то. Пишите - запрещено любое использование сего кода, если только у Вас нет персонального разрешения от меня. Юристы конечно прикопаются, но по факту - все законно. Но вот только не забудьте дать разрешения на просмотр лицензии, а то мало чего

Comment: Вообще не пишите никакую лицензию, во всех цивилизованных странах все права защищены и нет никаких разрешений по умолчанию

Comment: @andreymal это достоверная информация?

Comment: Ну так там есть уточнение - во всех цивилизованных странах. А с нецивилизованными никакая лицензия не поможет.